# App Bundle. Why layout expansion crashes on devices with Android 6.0.1?

Tags: android, android-layout, crash, android-app-bundle, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

We just deployed our app in App Bundle format to Google Play.
Our user base is 1.2 MAU.
No issues for most users.
Except a number of devices with Android 6.0.1 on board.
These devices crash mercilessly while trying to expand a layout for Notification.

Any ideas why the crash may happen on these devices?

Most devices are by Wileyfox manufacturer.
However there are 5 different models from Samsung, including these.
Galaxy Ace3
Galaxy A5

A bug report submitted to Google. More details inside.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132435772

Comment: File a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=398856&template=1084213) providing as much information as you can on the devices impacted and the stacktrace.

Comment: Wow, glad to see a Googler! We are doing our internal investigation. Trying to minimise the layout that crashes the user device. I'll file a bug as soon as we find out more. Thank you for taking care, Pierre.

Comment: Bug submitted https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132435772